# how to echo 10 keys each time to the end of key

Tags: php

i have loop of array like this

```
$num = 1;
foreach($setting["users"][$id]['url'] as $key => $value){
    $string .= "$num - $value $key ️\n️";
    $num++;
}
echo $string;
```

how can i `echo` 10 keys each time to the end of key like this

```
1- http://example1
2- http://example2
...
```

and again

```
11- http://example11
12- http://example12
...
```

i tried with `while` i get result from 1 to 10 keys but the second time i get result 20 from 1 to 20 i want to be from 11 to 20

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you're resetting `$num` to `1` inside the loop, and that is definitely going to cause some problems. The solution may be to simply move `$num = 1;` before the loop.

Comment: I'm trying to get result of 10 key each time as string until the keys end

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
$count=0;
foreach($setting["users"][$id]['url'] as $key => $value){
    for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
        echo(($i+$count) .' - ' .$value . $key . ️"\n️");
    }
    $count+=10;
}
```

I tried with a reduce version:

```
<?php
$count=0;
$things = ['first', 'second'];
foreach($things as $thing){
    for($i=1;$i<11;$i++){
        echo(($i+$count) .' - ' .$thing ." ️\n️");
    }
    $count+=10;
}
```

and the results are:

```
1 - first ️
️2 - first ️
️3 - first ️
️4 - first ️
️5 - first ️
️6 - first ️
️7 - first ️
️8 - first ️
️9 - first ️
️10 - first ️
️11 - second ️
️12 - second ️
️13 - second ️
️14 - second ️
️15 - second ️
️16 - second ️
️17 - second ️
️18 - second ️
️19 - second ️
️20 - second ️
```

Comment: Thank you, but that is not exactly what I want
I'm trying to get result of 10 keys each time as string until the keys end
first result of echo from 1 to 10 and continue second result  from 11 to 20 until the keys ends

Comment: okay, I think I get it now, I edited my answer, check if that's what you need @Skora

Comment: Sorry but again this is not what I needed
Let's say I have 25 key and value inside url array
when i use my code i get all the keys inside url
in one result I need to divide this result into several parts so that each part does not contain more than ten keys